# In Openlayers can i have zoom rates 3m, 4m

Tags: zooming, scale, openlayers

Im using Openlayers in my project and i want to add some additional zoom rates as 3m, 4m. In Openlayers site i can see some fixed zoom rates only 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/scale-line.html

The below is my resolutions array for metric zoom scale rates with added for 3m and 4m

```
'metric': [2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01]

which is like
          200m, 100m, 50m, 20m, 10m, 5m, 4m, 3m, 2m, 1m, 0.5m
```

With the above resolutions array im getting zooms for 4m and 3m in my map but in my scale display it shows as 5m for both 4m and 3m zooms. How can i make it display respective zoom rate on scale

Comment: The control is hardcoded to display only values with leading digits 1,2 and 5

Comment: Is there any way i can modify in Openlayers library js to display 3m, 4m zoom rates in scale ? or any hack i can do to make 3m, 4m display in scale ?

Comment: It might to easier to create your own display.  The line should stay the same length and the text could be updated at the `view.on('change:resolution', ...)` event to show a value based on the current resolution

Comment: I have looked into this change:resolution. Any code reference as to how the scale text alone can be changed from within this resolution change

Comment: I have worked on a hack like `view.on('change:resolution', func(evt) { var demo = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-scale-line-inner');
      demo[0].innerHTML = '3m'; })` and this seems to change the scale line text to 3m but problem is this function executes first and next the openlayers scaleLineControl executes which changes the resolution as per Openlayers library calculations

Comment: You will need to create your own div to display what looks like a scaleline (the length won't change) and update the text on that.

Answer (score 0):

you can check [scale-line](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/scale-line.html) on openlayers. It's measure value changes even a simple pan. Maybe you can use in a local area with a specific projection.

Comment: Even with this its not possible to show 3m, 4m in scale display as its hardcoded in Openlayers library as  `ol.control.ScaleLine.LEADING_DIGITS = [1, 2, 5]` Only to display scale rates with these leading digits